# AWS s3 Bucket cannot be deleted

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-console

Deletion of AWS S3 buckets is failing. I was using the Java SDK when it started failing. Now I have tried the same thing manually i.e. via the web console, but the same issue persists. Here is the screenshot of one of the buckets.

[image]

The error from the java code is below:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified bucket does not 
exist (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchBucket; Request `ID: 23349323451658FC; S3 Extended Request ID: `
ggx4OT58UvYJsaGCXJxJ6cx04tsfWpoW6B0JUCeE9wDxgK6uJqMFb6d4qbPhcNGuuwDZpdEklVs=), 
S3 Extended Request ID: 
ggx4OT58UvYJsaGCXJxJ6cx04tsfWpoW6B0JUCeE9wDxgK6uJqMFb6d4qbPhcNGuuwDZpdEklVs=
```

The aws-cli actually returns the buckets in contrast to the java sdk. See the output below;
`Y:\>aws s3 ls
2019-05-23 16:44:18 bucket-4a6aa2a3-d6c8-4ef8-b5ae-e02df4d6beca
2019-05-23 16:44:04 bucket-e519ae8f-0f59-4a37-87a0-c9d2d5749977`

**UPDATE** Without any changes, running the same Java application with the same credentials, the buckets just deleted. Completely **NO** idea what happened.

Comment: AWS Support might be a better resource than SO.

Comment: OK, i will try contacting them right away.

Comment: @SeanBright it seams support is not for `Support plan:Basic` like mine. Is there a way to contact them without paying. I tried via this page `https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home?region=us-west-1#`

Comment: Using equivalent credentials, what does the awscli tell you when you list buckets (using 'aws s3 ls')? Does the bucket exist?

Comment: @jarmod the buckets are listed using the aws-cli

Comment: Make sure that you have the correct permissions to delete buckets

Comment: @developing2020 i don't think the issue is with permissions. I have the correct permissions actually. I even log into the web-console using as root and delete still fails.

Comment: With respect to code: Can you check that you have set the correct region in your client when deleting the bucket? The error in your screenshot could be because of a S3 bucket policy in the bucket. Can you check that?

Comment: Have you set a bucket policy on this S3 bucket that may be preventing deletion? Also, is the bucket actually empty?

Comment: You have already deleted this bucket.  It should not be possible for the error message `The specified bucket does not 
exist... NoSuchBucket` to mean anything else.  The listing of buckets is eventually consistent -- they do not always disappear from the listing immediately after you delete them.